# Nodejs Profiling: What to do with v8.log file

Tags: javascript, node.js, profiling, profiler, v8

Only thing I have installed is Nodejs. 
I'm using Windows 8 x64.

I run my program via `node --prof app.js`.  It generates a v8.log file.

Now, what do I do with the v8.log file?

Comment: You need to compile V8 and run it through windows-tick-processor.bat

Comment: You should read the document : https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Starting with v5.2.0, Node.JS ships with a built-in tick processor:

```
node --prof-process
```

See the [release notes](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v5.2.0/) for more information.

Comment: Not sure why you're being downvoted.  It's also available in 4.4.0 (possibly earlier)

Answer (score 6):

Chrome's built-in [Trace Event Profiling Tool](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/trace-event-profiling-tool) (accessible in Chrome or Chromium at chrome://tracing) can build more-useful visualizations around v8.log output.

Note that dumps from node >= 0.11.x [may be more useful to you](http://rjzaworski.com/2014/12/profiling-node-js-on-linux) than those on the current stable release (0.10.35).

Comment: Looks like there is a bug, it's not working. I've reported it here: https://github.com/catapult-project/catapult/issues/4372

Comment: I can't get it to load in chrome://tracing either....I wish it did work though!

Answer (score 1):

You need to process the v8.log.  The v8 log contains sample points, and want to collect that data into something readable/usable.  Check out [node-tick-processor](https://github.com/sidorares/node-tick) and run that over your v8 log.

Comment: This answer is the most bare-minimal answer to this question - while it is definitely the smallest push in the right direction, a lot more could be done to help inquiring users. Would love to see more information about general usage and understanding the v8 log, or at least resources for understand v8.log